# I am on macOS I have tried clearing my old gitHub name online and locally and it just won't take locally, I still get old user name on commits

Tags: git, macos, github

I am learning git and git hub properly now with a class and I had an old account I was logged into. I have recently deleted that account from gitHub but seem to be plagued by it on my system.

Whenever I commit a local file its author is the old name I no longer have and when pushed to GitHub that name carries over.

I did the following so far:

```
git config user.name --unset
```

Then set it to my current user name. Running `git config -l` shows that the changes were updated.

Then I commit locally again and everything reverts back to old name. This is with fresh test folders and txt files in testing. Running this `git config -l` shows my old name and not the updated one it was just showing.

I also have tried:

```
git credential-osxkeychain erase
host=github.com
protocol=https
```

With the double enter at the end.This also does nothing. I went into keychain access as a last resort and cleared the entry that stores this with blanks because it won't let me delete it and it still commits with my old name.I have restarted my computer multiple times as well. [Picture of my old name with commit and config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtbGJ.png)

Comment: can you try `git config --global user.name "Your Name"git config --global user.email "youremail@yourdomain.com"`. The command saves the values in the global configuration file, ~/.gitconfig

Comment: That looks like it did it thank you Jatin!

Comment: would you mind if i add my comment as answer to your solution, and maybe you can accept that so that it may help others in the future :)

Comment: sure thing sounds good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is " You need to add your configuration with --global option. global username and password are associated with commits on all repositories on your system that don’t have repository-specific values.

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git config --global user.email "youremail@yourdomain.com"
```

The command saves the values in the global configuration file, `~/.gitconfig`

`NOTE :-`when you want to have commits only for a particular repository
~/yourcode/myapp directory. First, switch the repository root directory:

cd ~/yourcode/myapp

```
git config user.name "Your Name"
git config user.email "youremail@yourdomain.com"
```