# How to properly configure Git user name?

Tags: git, github

I'm starting to work with GitHub and Git. I created a repository called "Veterinary-management-system". After linking my directory to a remote origin, I decided to make a `git add .` and `git commit` and `push`. After doing so, the files were correctly uploaded but after checking the commits, the following is shown:

[image: Image #1]

As you can see the user "androso123" made the commit. I already checked which username is related with git (aj502gm):

[image: Image #2]

What should I do to make the "aj502gm" username appear as the commit's author?

Comment: as you are starting: please paste any text as (formatted) `text` rather as images. it's easier to read for visually impaired, and can be *searched* for (which is rather handy if you are looking for something)

Comment: You are confusing the user/email referenced inside each commit (aj502gm / androsogt@gmail.com - which you should see using `git log` locally or inspecting individual commits on github ) with the user logged in github who as the write permission to push the content. To change this last one you need to have this user available on github with correct permissions to access the repository and to change your github connection credentials (username/token or ssh key) used from your ide or command line.

Comment: did you try this first https://stackoverflow.com/a/67134202/13126651

Answer (score 1):

There are two different things going on here.

First, in your commits, there is a name and an email. [As outlined in the Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#user-name), what's in `user.name` is typically a personal name, not a username. Nothing in user.name has any affect on any account or authentication whatever, so there's no reason to set it to a username. For example, the maintainer of Git uses "Junio C Hamano". `user.email` is used for configuring the email address in the commit.

What you see on GitHub is a GitHub username, and the association with your commits is purely based on the email address in the commits (usually, the setting of `user.email` when you made the commit). For example, if I use the email address I normally use at home, GitHub will associate those with the user bk2204. This correspondence is set up in the settings, and only one account can be associated with an email address at a time.

If you want your commits to be associated with a different account, then they must use an email address associated with that account. If you create commits where the email address is not associated with any account, then GitHub will not show an account and will instead show the value set as the (personal) name in the commit (e.g., "Pat Roe").